# How to retrieve and use row(s) from database in HTML page?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

In my APEX application, I would like to use rows from query as variables, but I don't want to create items for each element. Those variables I will have to show in my custom HTML page.

For example this is query:

```
SELECT cells.id as id, cells.name as name, storage.capacity as capacity from cells, storage WHERE storage.capacity > 120
```

Then in my custom HTML code I would like to reference those rows, something like this(sorry I don't know the syntax of variables):

```
<div>#name[1]#</div><a href="p?#id[1]"...
<div>#name[2]#</div><a href="p?#id[2]"...
```

So how can I do it for single fetched row and for multiple rows? Which type of process and region to engage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create items for each element MANUALLY, you can use region of type `Form on table or view`. APEX creates them automatically. If you don't want to create items automatically, you can create region of type `HTML`, then go to `Region Definition` -> `Identification`, select `Type` - `PL/SQL (anonymous block)`, `Source` - type your PL/SQL code there. Example:

```
declare
  ...
begin
  for i in (select text_col, rownum from mytable) loop
    htp.p(apex_item.text(rownum, text_col) || '<br>');
  end loop;
end;
```

You can pass to procedure `htp.p` any string variables. If they contain valid HTML, it will be displayed properly, otherwise you will see your HTML source code. Also you can use `apex_item` (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/apex_item.htm#AEAPI192) package to generate HTML code of required items.

Comment: Dmitry, as always thanks for prompt response. Could you please bring an example how I store and reference records? Do I have to store query result into some collection(using SELECT/INSERT?), then use some syntax to access each record from `htp.p`? Just so I go in the right direction.

Comment: I modified my answer and added there an example. In this way you store on the page PL/SQL code, that generates web page every time when user opens it. Page contain data, that present in DB at the generation moment.

Comment: That works like a charm, although I used something like i.text_col inside loop. Thanks again!